# Why is namespace required to differentiate identifiers in templates for different apps?

Tags: django, namespaces

The Django tutorial on [Namespacing URL names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names) describes that main `urlpatterns` can specify a `namespace` when including `urls` for a app, like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    ...
```

Then namespace is used to differentiate references when rendering a template, as `'polls:detail'`, like:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

But, as I understand, the apps are already differentiated based on directory location, like in this case "pools/" for the "pools" app., then why is this `namespace` indication needed, when templates are located under the app directory?

Does the use of `namespace` mean that templates for an imported app must be modified in order to match the chosen `namespace` value in the `include`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace can be useful then different apps have urls with the same name.  How do you suppose differentiate `detail` url at the `polls` app from `detail` url at the `profiles` app?  With namespaces you can use `polls:detail` and `profiles:detail` without any conflicts.

Namespaces also allow you to attach the one app to different urls in the single project.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^other_polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="other_polls")),
    ...
)
```

Comment: With `detail` url in two apps, I would expect that separate code is used based on url decode in project "urls.py", so it is known what app the `detail` is relevant for.  But with two different urls for same app, and thus **same** code, how can the two different namespace references be used in the code?  Hmm... there is probably some important concept I am missing here.

Comment: It is all described in the URL dispatcher documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Comment: Thanks for the reference :-D